# Ant fails to create .pkg file during maven build on JDK9

Tags: java, maven, ant, maven-3, maven-plugin

I'm upgrading the build process of a javaFx application from JDK8 to JDK9 and I'm running into problems.

The build process is run by Maven and using Ant to bundle the jar file into a pkg file (on Mac Osx) and into a MSI file in Windows.

Maven version: 3.5.2. Ant version:

I'm getting an exception during the execution of the build :

```
com.oracle.tools.packager.ConfigException: java.lang.RuntimeException: File /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-9.0.4.jdk/Contents/Home/jmods does not belong to <our project binaries folder>
    at jdk.packager/com.oracle.tools.packager.mac.MacPkgBundler.validate(MacPkgBundler.java:568)
    at jdk.packager/com.sun.javafx.tools.packager.PackagerLib.generateNativeBundles(PackagerLib.java:370)
    at jdk.packager/com.sun.javafx.tools.packager.PackagerLib.generateDeploymentPackages(PackagerLib.java:348)
    at com.sun.javafx.tools.ant.DeployFXTask.execute(DeployFXTask.java:310)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:292)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor30.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:435)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:456)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1393)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.SingleCheckExecutor.executeTargets(SingleCheckExecutor.java:38)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1248)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Ant.execute(Ant.java:441)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:292)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor30.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:435)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:456)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1393)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTarget(Project.java:1364)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.antrun.AntRunMojo.execute(AntRunMojo.java:313)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:134)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:208)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:154)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:146)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:309)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:194)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:107)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:955)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:290)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:194)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
```

In maven I'm using the following plugins (all upgraded to the most up to date version):

- maven-resources-plugin: 3.0.2
- maven-dependency-plugin: 3.0.2
- exec-maven-plugin: 1.6.0
- maven-compiler-plugin: 3.7.0 (configured to use jdk 9)
- maven-surefire-plugin: 2.20.1

**The build fails in the fx:deply task which is configured in our build.xml like this:**

```
<fx:deploy width="600" height="400" install="true"
        verbose="true" nativeBundles="${native.bundles}" 
        outdir="${dist.dir}/bundle" outfile="${app.name}" >

        <fx:application id="${app.id}" name="${app.name}" mainClass="${javafx.main.class}" version="${app.version}" />

        <fx:preferences shortcut="true" menu="false" install="true"/>
        <fx:secondaryLauncher 
            mainClass="com.pingidentity.proxy.proxyhelper.ProxyExternalEntryPoint"
            name="ProxyHelperSetup"/>
        <fx:secondaryLauncher 
            mainClass="com.pingidentity.proxy.proxyhelper.AutoUpdatesExternalEntryPoint"
            name="AutoUpdatesSetup"/>
        <fx:secondaryLauncher
            mainClass="com.pingidentity.proxy.proxyhelper.MigrationHelper" 
            name="MigrationHelperSetup"/>
        <fx:resources >
            <fx:fileset dir="${dist.dir}" includes="${jar.name}"/>
            <fx:fileset dir="${dist.dir}/lib" />
            <fx:fileset dir="${resources.dir}"  type="license" includes="license.rtf"/>
                <fx:fileset dir="${resources.dir}"  type="license" includes="testwelcome.rtf"/>
            <fx:fileset dir="${basedir}/UnlimitedJCEPolicy" includes="*.jar" />
            <!-- the attr os="mac" not works, so I created emtpy folder in case of windows -->
            <fx:fileset dir="${dist.dir}/uninstaller" />
        </fx:resources>
        <fx:info  title="${app.name}" vendor="${vendor}" category="public.app-category.productivity">
        </fx:info>

        <fx:platform>
            <fx:jvmarg value="-Xms128m"/>
            <fx:jvmarg value="-Xmx384m"/>
            <fx:jvmarg value="-Xmn64m"/>
        </fx:platform>

        <fx:bundleArgument arg="mac.CFBundleVersion" value="${app.version}"/>
        <fx:bundleArgument arg="mac.signing-key-developer-id-app" value="Developer ID Application: Ping Identity Corporation (6U3RF4C84N)"/>
        <fx:bundleArgument arg="mac.signing-key-developer-id-installer" value="Developer ID Installer: Ping Identity Corporation (6U3RF4C84N)"/>
            <fx:bundleArgument arg="mainJar" value="${dist.dir}/${jar.name}" />

    </fx:deploy>
```

Any thoughts ideas how to make this work with JDK 9?

Comment: are you building this in a OSX environment? Do you have the possibility to try build it in a different OSX version or on other OS?

Comment: I found out that adding this line makes the error go away :
<fx:deploy>
.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found out that adding this line makes the error go away :
build.xml -> fx:deploy ->

```
<fx:runtime strip-native-commands="false">
    <fx:add-modules value="java.base"/>
    <fx:module-path value="${java.home}/jmods"/>
    <fx:module-path value="${basedir}/modules"/>
</fx:runtime>
```